# Scalability versus Responsiveness in .NET Async

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, scalability

I'm reading through the [Exam Ref 70-483: Programming in C#](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145374318.do) book and the following code sample is given:

#### LISTING 1-19

```
public Task SleepAsyncA(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    return Task.Run(() => thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
}

public Task SleepAsyncB(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    var t = new Timer(delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, -1, -1);
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(t);
    t.Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The paragraph under states this:

> The `SleepAsyncA` method uses a thread from the thread pool while
>   sleeping.  the second method, however, which has a completely
>   different implementation, does not occupy a thread while waiting for
>   the timer to run.  The second method gives you scalability.

Why is A responsive but B scalable?

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you believe "responsive" means?

Comment: Actually, I'm a little unsure as well.  the only example I can think of is a UI not being thread locked.

Comment: Is this the full question on the book? Is there an explanation? The first case would make a client UI more responsive and the second would make a web application (server) more scalable but would also make a client UI more responsive while the first would never make a web application more responsive and would make it less scalable.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It's not a question, but the quote and sample are lifted directly from it.

Comment: @BanksySan, I was able to download a sample chapter with that section (Using async and await) an read that part several times. I also think the author pulled the scalability issue out of nowhere. The whole text seems to talk only about client UIs and without any explanation introduces server scalability.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It was a bit of a curve ball, I thought either I'd missed something or it was rudimentary and I just wasn't getting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the starting point would have no process/thread/task control and be a non-responsive spinning loop, checking if the time has passed e.g.:

```
public void SleepBadly(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var stopTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(millisecondsTimeout);
    while (DateTime.UtcNow < stopTime) {}
    return;
}
```

SleepAsyncA sleeps the thread rather than spinning so it doesn't use any CPU, so would be **responsive** as the CPU is *available*, but it is still using the thread while it sleeps.

SleepAsyncB gives up the thread while it waits, so it doesn't use CPU and that thread can be used for something else; so it is **responsive** *and* **scalable**.

For example, at scale, if you had 100,000 calls outstanding in SleepAsyncA; either you would have exhausted the threadpool and they would start queuing or you would have 100,000 active threads, neither of which is very good for scalability.

SleepAsyncB on the other hand would be using 0 threads while the 100,000 calls were waiting and doing nothing is infinitely more scalable than doing something.

However, while SleepAsyncB is a good example of how to use Task constructs like TaskCompletionSource, what you'd probably want to actually do in this example is:

```
public Task SleepAsyncC(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    return Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A is **responsive** because it has the appearance of asynchronicity by not blocking a thread which is important to the user. The UI remains fluid, but it is not scalable, because under the hood it ties up a limited resource (by blocking a thread).

B is still **responsive**, but also **scalable**, because it is truly asynchronous rather than merely giving the appearance of being so. It does not tie up any limited resources, even as the UI remains fluid.